# Problems using ajax to load into a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use the $.get() function to load a portion of a website into a variable to us later.  The code I currently have is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var container;
function loadData(data, targetVar) {
  container = data;
}

$.get('page.html#div', loadData(container));
```

the problem is the callback function keeps firing before the page loads leaving the variable with an undefined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to load part of the remote document, you could use `.load` method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#container_id').load('page.html #div');
}
```

Comment: Had to reword the page and this was what I went with. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are executing function with this code:

```
loadData(container)
```

This means that you are not passing handler to function, but results of your function. You also need to pass data returned by `$.get` into your function.

You can put it inside anonymous function:

```
$.get('page.html#div', function(data) { loadData(data, container); });
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result using the anonymous function call